# How to set Height of Fancybox iFrame v 2.1?

Tags: javascript, .net, fancybox

Here is my Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#popup").fancybox({
            'width': 500,
            'height': '500',
            'transitionIn': 'elastic',
            'transitionOut': 'elastic',
            'type': 'iframe'
        });
    });
</script>
```

width of iframe is set, but Height is not set.
Please let me know where am I going wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got it solved by doing this...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#popup").fancybox({
            fitToView: false,
            autoSize: false,
            autoDimensions: false,
            width: 520,
            height: 310,
            title: 'Login',
            helpers: {
                title: {
                    type: 'float'
                },
            },
            'transitionIn': 'elastic',
            'transitionOut': 'elastic'
        });
    });
```

Thanks, Anyway...

Answer (score 2):

Your height variable value should be a number, right now you have it as a string.  So your code should look more like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#popup").fancybox({
            'width': 500,
            'height': 500,
            'transitionIn': 'elastic',
            'transitionOut': 'elastic',
            'type': 'iframe'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have the classes "fancybox" and "fancybox.iframe" on your element, the minimum that is needed to accomplish what you need is:

```
$('.fancybox').fancybox({
        autoSize: false,
        width: 400,
        height: 400
});
```